# MySQL concatenation when there are null fields

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I created a VIEW using this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW aaa AS

   SELECT pry.uid, 
          treg.nombre_es as region, 
          tpais.nombre_es as pais, 
          tdep.departamento, 
          dep_other, tciu.ciudad, 
          ciu_other
     FROM tx_oriproyectos_proyectos AS pry
LEFT JOIN tx_oritablascomunes_regiones as treg ON pry.region = treg.uid
LEFT JOIN tx_oritablascomunes_paises as tpais ON pry.pais = tpais.uid
LEFT JOIN tx_oritablascomunes_departamentos as tdep ON pry.departamento = tdep.uid
LEFT JOIN tx_oritablascomunes_ciudades as tciu ON pry.ciudad = tciu.uid
```

And I obtained this and is Ok:

[result http://finewebdesigns.com/images/mysql_view_result.jpg](http://finewebdesigns.com/images/mysql_view_result.jpg)

And now I need to obtain concatenate results like this:

```
concatenated_field
---------------------------------------
Africa - ALbania - Tirana1 - Tirana2
Africa - Colombia - Guaviare - Calamar
```

How can I do that?

---

I tried this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW aaa AS

SELECT CONCAT_WS (' - ', pry.uid, treg.nombre_es as region, tpais.nombre_es as pais, tdep.departamento, dep_other, tciu.ciudad, ciu_other)
FROM tx_oriproyectos_proyectos AS pry
LEFT JOIN tx_oritablascomunes_regiones as treg
ON pry.region=treg.uid
LEFT JOIN tx_oritablascomunes_paises as tpais
ON pry.pais=tpais.uid
LEFT JOIN tx_oritablascomunes_departamentos as tdep
ON pry.departamento=tdep.uid
LEFT JOIN tx_oritablascomunes_ciudades as tciu
ON pry.ciudad=tciu.uid
```

But I obtained:

```
#1583 - Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'CONCAT_WS'
```

---

Ok, Thanks to @Mat I finally get this code, that is the expected solution to this problem.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW aaa AS

SELECT pry.uid, CONCAT_WS (' - ', treg.nombre_es, tpais.nombre_es, tdep.departamento, NULLIF(dep_other,''), tciu.ciudad, NULLIF(ciu_other,''))
FROM tx_oriproyectos_proyectos AS pry
LEFT JOIN tx_oritablascomunes_regiones as treg
ON pry.region=treg.uid
LEFT JOIN tx_oritablascomunes_paises as tpais
ON pry.pais=tpais.uid
LEFT JOIN tx_oritablascomunes_departamentos as tdep
ON pry.departamento=tdep.uid
LEFT JOIN tx_oritablascomunes_ciudades as tciu
ON pry.ciudad=tciu.uid
```

That obtains this: http://finewebdesigns.com/images/mysql_view_result_solved.jpg

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Comment: I tried different combinations using concat with no successful result.

Comment: You're aliasing fields inside your concat_ws call - there's no point in that, since the fields themselves will 'vanish' once the concat's completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`CONCAT_WS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) string function.

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' - ', treg.nombre_es, tpais.nombre_es, ...) FROM ...
```

From the docs:

> CONCAT_WS() does not skip empty strings. However, it does skip any NULL values after the separator argument.

so your null values will simply be ignored.

If you also want to skip empty strings, you can use throw the `NULLIF` function in the mix, as suggested by [ypercube](https://stackoverflow.com/users/344949/ypercube):

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' - ', NULLIF(col,''), ...) ...
```

Comment: or using `NULLIF()` function: `SELECT CONCAT_WS(' - ', NULLIF(col,''), ...)`

Comment: I was looking for that, and completely failing, when it's right there in the same docs as the `CASE` statement... Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks @Mat, I did so that you suggested, but returns error. Please see above.

Comment: Remove the `as name` parts, they make no sense inside that function call.

Comment: Now it works! But I don't know why the codification was changed. Please look: http://finewebdesigns.com/images/mysql_view_result_2.jpg

Comment: That's strange. What type is the uid column, and do you really want it in there?

Comment: You're right @Mat I don't need it there. Please see the edited question above. Thanks.